# react Carousel from scratch logic with visibility

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what's the logic or algorithm for a Carousel? I'm done my research for 1 item per display but in my case I need to display 3 items, when I click on the next I expect the first item is hidden and the 4th item appear.

```
<div className="App">
      <div className="Container">
        {items.map((item, i) => (
          <div className={`item ${i < lastIndex ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}>
            {item.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="prev">{"<"}</div>
      <div className="next">{">"}</div>
    </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-babbage-djron?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to keep track of the first and last index that should be displayed. Anything outside them, you can skip

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const items = [
  {
    name: "box 1"
  },
  {
    name: "box 2"
  },
  {
    name: "box 3"
  },
  {
    name: "box 4"
  },
  {
    name: "box 5"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [firstIndex, setFirstIndex] = useState(0);
  const [lastIndex, setLastIndex] = useState(3);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <h1>{lastIndex}</h1> */}
      <div className="Container">
        {items.map((item, i) => {
          if (i >= firstIndex && i < lastIndex) {
            return (
              <div key={item.name} className={"visible"}>
                {item.name}
              </div>
            );
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })}
      </div>
      <div
        className="prev"
        onClick={() => {
          if (firstIndex > 0) {
            setFirstIndex(firstIndex - 1);
            setLastIndex(lastIndex - 1);
          }
        }}
      >
        {"<"}
      </div>
      <div
        className="next"
        onClick={() => {
          if (lastIndex < items.length) {
            setFirstIndex(firstIndex + 1);
            setLastIndex(lastIndex + 1);
          }
        }}
      >
        {">"}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-banach-6bfh2?file=/src/App.js

**EDIT** Updated the code to prevent first and last index going out of bound of items length

Comment: hmm need to prevent clicking if the last index is the end.

Comment: Updated the code sample to prevent firstIndex going below 0 and lastIndex going over items.length

Comment: thanks so much. what if I want to hide the arrow of right / left according to the first / last index? do I need to do calculation?

Comment: You could do a conditional render. See the conditions I have put in the onClick? You can take them out from the onClick and encompass the whole div with the conditional render. I updated the codesandbox to show it

Comment: cool, but can't do transition if don't use opacity isn't it? it doesn't slide though..

Comment: There are a lot of different ways you could do transitions and animations on the components. From (React documentation)[https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html] you can use transition groups. I believe there are some other modules you can get to add any animation you want on it

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help for you!

```
export default function App() {
  const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(1);
  const [lastIndex, setLastIndex] = useState(3);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Container">
        {
          items.map((item, i) => {
            if (i >= startIndex - 1 && i <= lastIndex)
              return (
                <div className={`item ${i < lastIndex ? "visible" : "hidden"}`} key={i}>
                  {item.name}
                </div>
              )
          })
        }
      </div>
      <div className="prev"
        onClick={() => {
          setStartIndex(startIndex - 1)
          setLastIndex(lastIndex - 1)
        }}
      >{"<"}</div>
      <div className="next"
        onClick={() => {
          setStartIndex(startIndex + 1)
          setLastIndex(lastIndex + 1)
        }}
      >
        {">"}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```